# How to fix TypeSrcipt error "Object is possibly 'undefined' " with virtual mongoose attribute

Tags: typescript, mongoose

When trying to calculate a virtual property model I get: Object is possibly 'null' If possible I would prefer not suppressing the typescript's strict rule.

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const SymbolSchema = new Schema({
  max: Number,
  min: Number, 

});

export interface Symbol {
  max: number;
  min: number;
}

export default model("Symbol", SymbolSchema);

SymbolSchema.virtual("diff").get(() => {
 return this ? (this?.max - this?.min ): 0
// this error : Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
});
```

also have checked `this`  but the `ts(2532)` error occurs
so how to solve it?

Comment: what version of TS?Your example works perfectly fine in TS playground

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use `this` and an arrow function together in this case because you need  `this` to be an instance of a model and not this whole module:

```js
SymbolSchema.virtual("diff").get(function(this:Symbol) {
 return this ? (this?.max - this?.min ): 0
// this error : Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
});
```

Comment: ah, that's it. this works nice:
`
SymbolSchema.virtual("diff").get(function(this:Symbol) {
 return this ? (this?.max - this?.min ): 0
});
`

Comment: this answer is also valid if you are facing a similar problem with `pre`